# python3 - Selenium keeps clicking

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am using Selenium with Python3 on Windows 10.

Everything works fine but when I make it click load more button,

it keeps clicking until it find nothing to click.

All I want is just exact one time of click. Any ideas or solution for this?

```
    <!-- language: lang-python -->
    from selenium import webdriver

    browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="")
    ...


    loadBtn = browser.find_element_by_id("byscripts_ajax_posts_loader_trigger")
    loadBtn.click()  # it keeps clicking almost limitlessly!!
    browser.implicitly_wait(10)
```

Comment: Are you sure that line isn't in a loop? Put a breakpoint on that line and then step through your code and see what's going on.

Comment: Also, you should read up on `implicitly_wait()`. It doesn't behave the way you think it does. It's set once for the life of the driver. It does not wait 10s when you call it. You want a `WebDriverWait` for that purpose.

Comment: Thx! I solved this problem!